# Destructuring as second parameter in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I am trying to do a simple example of destructuring on ES6 for a function with default parameters **in Firefox 51**. This works as expected:

```
const work = ({ param = 'a' }) => console.log(param);
work({});
```

However, when we try to do the destructuring as the second parameter:

```
const nowork = (ignore, { param = 'a' }) => console.log(param);
nowork('', {});
```

I get this error in the terminal:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

So the question is, **is anything wrong with my code or is it a Firefox bug**? The same code works on Chrome. [Test it in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/txdz6heL/) (comment/uncomment and open the console).

Edit: note that this is almost the same code as [an example on Mozilla Hacks from 2015](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).

Comment: Does the error remain if you remove the default?

Comment: @torazaburo No, it does not seem to. Tested on Firefox 50.0.2.

Comment: I think you can use babel to fix cross browser issues，see code compiled http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=const%20nowork%20%3D%20(ignore%2C%20%7B%20param%20%3D%20'a'%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(param)%3B%0D%0Anowork(''%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B

Comment: I think it is a firefox bug

Comment: I found a workaround, explicitly adding the second parameter as an object: `(ignore, { param = 'a' } = {})`. However the example on Mozilla Hacks didn't seem to use that, so it might be as well that it was for an early/draft implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, explicitly telling that the expected parameter is an object:

```
const workagain = (ignore, { param = 'a' } = {}) => console.log(param);
workagain(null, {});
```

I don't really know why it works and my original (and Mozilla's) example doesn't work though.

Comment: For future reference, I've [opened a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1342837) on BugZilla.

Comment: @AndrewLi awesome, thanks. However maybe you could link to this question or add the extra info that with only one parameter it works? It seems relevant to the bug.

Comment: For the sake of verification, can you make sure that if the destructed parameter is the first argument and the ignored parameter the second that it works? I currently can't.

Comment: It seems to work for me, you mean this, right? https://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/txdz6heL/2/

Comment: Looks like [it was a Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1204024). It's been fixed in Firefox 52.